# golang fetch all all filepathes from compiled file

Tags: go, refactoring, runtime

I am trying to fetch all source files that where used during compilation.
Function runtime.Caller() and panic with its stacktrace show this info.

I need something like this

```
func fetchUsedFiles() []string {
    ....
}
func main() {
    log.Println("Used Files",fetchUsedFiles())
}
```

UPD:

All what I need is read somehow "runtime.firstmoduledata" variable content. But it is not exported variable.

Comment: I use `go list -f "{{.ImportPath}} {{.Deps}}" my/program` to get all the dependencies, and I go get them in a temporary sub-folder. I use that to vendor dependencies: https://gist.github.com/VonC/51fe08c5bd79334b6e1ccdd498d4d2bc. But that not be what you need or meant by "fetch all source files that where used during compilation"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I have combined VonC answer and my runtime approcah.

All needed data stored at `runtime.firstmoduledata` - struct but they are not exported. To read data from there I read my executable file again (implemented only for ELF), find this symbol and do the other part like runtime.Caller() function. This method is not portable and can be broken by changes in runtime library but it works.

`selfReflect` function uses copies of private types from runtime lib

https://github.com/martende/restartable/blob/master/restartable.go#L208

```
func selfReflect(filename string) ([]string,error) {
    f,err := elf.Open(filename)
    if err != nil {
        return nil,err
    }
    defer f.Close()
    syms,err := f.Symbols()
    if err != nil {
        return nil,err
    }
    var modSym elf.Symbol
    var modSymFound = false
    for _,v := range syms {
        if v.Name == "runtime.firstmoduledata" {
            modSym = v
            modSymFound = true
            break
        }
    }
    if ! modSymFound {
        return nil,errors.New("elfparse:nosym")
    }

    var datap = (*moduledata)(unsafe.Pointer(uintptr(modSym.Value)))

    files := make([]string,0)
    for i := range datap.filetab {
        bp := &datap.pclntable[datap.filetab[i]]
        file := C.GoString( (*C.char) (unsafe.Pointer(bp))  )
        if file != "<autogenerated>" && file != "@" {
            if _, err := os.Stat(file); err == nil {
                files = append(files ,file)
            }
        }
    }


    return files,nil
}
```

Comment: @VonC. I want to track files that where used during compilation and silently recompile and restart server.

Comment: OK, that is clearer now. You can add this as a description to your https://github.com/martende/restartable repo.

Comment: @VonC moduledata allows, for example, to get address of all strings in the executable, enumerate the strings, keep the strings in a hashtable. This can allow to improve performance of the functions which operate with strings.

Comment: @Larytet OK, and I see it is still being updated: https://github.com/golang/go/commit/350b74bc4b9f37ba29ef02c2f89d687ae8563a05

Comment: @VonC, you can find an example of my code here  https://github.com/larytet/binlog/blob/master/binlog_test.go#L86